# Program will not allow me to update a Datetime column in an SQL server using the .net connectior for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datetime

I am writing a program that interacts and monitors a hardware device. I like to be able to log what the current status and what time it checked it.

I have already tested to ensure that there is a connection between the program and the hardware device, and the program and the SQL Server. And that connection is fine.

I have tried only updating the status, and that works find. But when I update the status and the `lastupdated column`, it gives an Inner Exception that says

```
"Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'lastupdated'. Table: 'logModel.Store.statuslog_current_log'."
```

Also note that the lastupdated column in the SQL table is of the type, DateTime. Also the SQL server is a MySQL server, and I am using C# on Visual Studio 2015 and using the .Net Connector for MySQL.

Here is the code I am using,

```
if (data != null && data[0] >= 0 && data[1] >= 0 && data[2] >=0 && data[3] >= 0)
{
    List<statuslog_current_display> result = db.statuslog_current_display.Where<statuslog_current_display>(m => m.doorid == DoorID).ToList();
    foreach (statuslog_current_display status in result)
    {
        status.statuscode = (int) data[1];
        status.lastupdated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
try {
    db.SaveChanges();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorHandler.showErrorMessage(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Your code, and the solution you posted below, make this seem like you're using an Entity Framework data model. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Allow Zero Datetime=True;` to end of your connection String.

This can be happen when DATETIME or DATE field contains an invalid value. According to that your default value for the column can be considered an invalid date.

Comment: Problem with that is that the database has the lastupdated column to to have  a "not null" flag. So the lastupdated column can never be null. Anyway, I added the code you said to my connection string that was specified in the App.config file. There was no change in anything.

Comment: @user3346931 add this also-  Convert Zero Datetime=true;

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I managed to get it to work by changing the StoreGeneratedPattern in the model editor (since I made this using ADO.NET designer) from Identity To None. This might have something to do with the fact that in the database, it used to be TIMESTAMP variable instead of a DATETIME variable.